# Change user in shell function?

Tags: shell, su

I would like to change the user within a shell function. I guess its not possible to change the user in such a enclosed function, but is there another way to achieve something like that?:

```
myFunction() {
    user=$1
    echo "Changing user to $user"
    su - $user
    whoami
    [do my stuff here for this user]
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the commands you want run by "user" in a script, then run the script using `sudo`, which you should use instead of `su`.

For example:

```
myFunction() {
    user="$1"
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    echo "date" >> $tmpfile
    # ... put other stuff in tmpfile
    sudo -u $user $tmpfile
    rm $tmpfile
}
```

Comment: Ok. Understand. Thank you very much for your help.